# Passing parameters thru Ruby's OAuth

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra

I'm using Mirven's [Twitter OAuth Sinatra](http://github.com/mirven/twitter-oauth-sinatra/) example and trying to figure out how I can send a 'next page' parameter with the Oauth request:

ie. The user attempts to visit `/edit/profile` which requires a login so I redirect to `/request` which deals with login via twitter - I now want to be able to redirect the user to the address they were originally looking for if they log in successfully.

I thought I could do this in the `.get_request_token` [line](http://github.com/mirven/twitter-oauth-sinatra/blob/master/app.rb#L47) with this code:

```
  @request_token = @consumer.get_request_token({:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host}/auth"},{:next => params['next'] || '/'})
```

But `params` has no additional items in the `/auth` handler.

I'm new to OAuth, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simpler than I thought, just add your parameters to the oauth_callback url like so:

```
  @request_token = @consumer.get_request_token({:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host}/auth"},{:next => params['next'] || '/'})
```

Then put logic in your `/auth` handler to redirect according to `params['next']`